# Word for a number without formatting

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, numbers

I have two representations of numbers, one is with thousands separators that are localized based on country so `1,234,567.89` for English and `1.234.567,89` for German, for example. This representation I'm calling "formatted"

The other is the "plain" representation of the number, in this case `1234567.89`. Is there a good term for this numeric, can-be-used-in-calculations representation?

Comment: Is there something wrong with "unformatted"?

Comment: "unformatted" is more or less what we already use, but it doesn't convey the can-be-used-in-calculations part. This is in a software context where the "formatted" numbers are store as strings, while the "plain"/"unformatted" ones are stored as numbers.

Comment: Why are you storing formatted numbersas strings?  Why not just store the numerical value and format on-the-fly only when you need to print them?

Comment: @Jim I'm asking precisely because I'm stumped on what to call the on-the-fly converters that print them. The naming is both for the code and for communicating to non-technical people.

Answer (score -1):

An interesting question where the answer depends much more on defined convention than on dictionary usage. Your "plain" number and your "formatted" number are both "decimal" numbers.

Your "formatted" number is better termed a "grouped" decimal because of the international standards that apply:

> A comma or a dot on a line are reaffirmed as decimal marker symbols, and not as grouping symbols in order to facilitate reading;
>
> "numbers may be divided in groups of three in order to facilitate reading;
>
> neither dots nor commas are ever inserted in the spaces between groups".
>
> [General Conference on Weights and Measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Conference_on_Weights_and_Measures)

Previous usage had groupings such as 123,234,432.993 but the use of commas and stops was potentially confusing and it makes sense to do away with all except the decimal separator (either the stop or the comma). You may see the confusion in examples like your own, or in this:

> GB-English 4,294,967,295.000
>
> Italian    4.294.967.295,000
>
> https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html

The general conference specified the comma and the dot as decimal separators. It also specified that grouping should be done with spaces. Hence:

1234567.89 (or 1234567,89) are decimals

and 1 234 567.89 (or 1 234 567,89) may be termed "grouped decimals".

Answer (score -1):

The written form of the numbers are all represented by the same to the computer.
All three of the forms (1,234.56 / 1.234,56 / 1234.56) could be considered 'formatted'. That is because they are all representations of [floating-point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Floating-point_numbers).

It's not a single word, but **floating-point representation** would work for *numeric, can-be-used-in-calculations representation*.

A floating-point representation is the reason that a normal-looking number like 10.1 sometimes will get printed as 10.09999998. (The fractional 0.1 is a represented by a repeated binary mantissa.)

Comment: A great question on our sister site, StackOverflow, wonders "Is floating point math broken?" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken/588014#588014). And even if you're a veteran in the world of floating-point numbers, a great article is "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic", which was reprinted at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html .

Comment: All very true, and relevant to the digital computational handling of number, but the question asks for English terms to describe the representation; it does not ask about technical computational aspects of rounding  or significant digits.

Comment: But the OP may be lacking the concept that *all* of the numbers are formatted, even the plain "1234567.89".

Comment: This is likely the technically correct answer. The context is software and the reason I specified `"1,234,567.89"` as "formatted" while `1234567.89" as "plain" is because the former is stored as a string and the later as a number (JavaScript, so always float). Calling it just a "number" is ambiguous, as one could argue "they're all numbers." Floating-point is indeed more correct, but not a familiar term in the context where it would be used.

Comment: I disagree that *floating point* is the technically correct answer. Floating point representation is a machine format.  It allows the decimal point to “float” back and forth (as described by the exponent) within the mantissa (significant digits).  The number as formatted is not in floating point form - the decimal place is fixed between the ones digit and the tenths digit.

Comment: @Jim I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "the decimal place is fixed," wouldn't the case for floating point representations also be that the decimal is located between the ones and tenths digits? Those digits would be named by the location of the decimal. Also, to clarify, the numbers don't have to have exactly two decimal places.

Comment: @mayacoda - As I said, floating point is a machine representation.  The closest thing to it in the pen and paper world is scientific notation.  To your question a float is (notionally) represented by a mantissa and an exponent. (Let’s not get into gory details about, for example, IEEE-754)  The mantissa is just a string of numbers without a decimal point:  123456.  The desired decimal point location is specified by the exponent.  And so by changing the exponent I can make the decimal point “float around”  1.23456   Or 123.456  Or even 1234560000.  etc.  That’s why it’s called floating point.

Comment: The question was not posed as a computational matter. If that was the intention it should not have appeared on a site about English usage, and should now be moved.

Comment: Where else do you format a number but in the computational realm? And why would you downvote the *answer*? I stand by my premise: all of these numbers are formatted, even the plain one.

Comment: @rajah9 Numbers are used in computation (which the PO did not mention - they mentioned *calculation*) but there is a parallel world where numbers are represented (as the PO used the term)  in reports, on the printed page (remember that?), in statistical digests, in engineering specifications and in all the many places where roughly 7 600 000 000 people apply number to the description of the universe and to human affairs. The question started with that type of use of number and I see no reason to assume it to be uniquely about digital computation. Or we should have mentioned "integer" too?